# Decoding umlauts in URLs (or composite vs precomposed encoding)

Tags: http, winapi, unicode, utf-8, url-encoding

My application processes URLs.

One example is below:

https://127.0.0.1/Datei_Verz._Änderung.gif

What the browser sends is:

https://127.0.0.1/Datei_Verz._%C3%84nderung.gif

When this is unescaped (using [AtlUnescapeUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91k6ha41.aspx)), the %C3 and %84 are seen as distinct characters and so I end up with:

https://127.0.0.1/Datei_Verz._Ã„nderung.gif

So the unescape doesn't recognize that the browser sent a composite character as opposed to a precomposed (using the explanation from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Ideally the browser would have represented Ä by the single Unicode code point LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS (U+00C4) which I assume could have been %00C4 in the URL.

So how does one decode the initial URL?

Comment: Can you use .NET? [WebUtility.UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urldecode.aspx) should do it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't to do with Unicode normalisation (precomposed characters vs decomposed character sequences). It's just a case of wrong byte encoding.

> Ideally the browser would have represented Ä by the single Unicode code point LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS (U+00C4) which I assume could have been %00C4 in the URL.

Nope: URL-encoding is a byte-based encoding; %-escapes are strictly two digits (one byte) so `%00C4` would be a zero byte followed by the literal characters `C4`.

There is no %-encoding that covers one code point with a single escape sequence. Unicode URL components have to be encoded to bytes before being escaped to `%nn` sequences.

`%C4` would be the encoding for `Ä` for a web application based around ISO-8859-1 or code page 1252, but the encoding most web applications use today (and which is mandated by the IRI standard) is UTF-8. `%C3%84` is the correct encoding of `Ä` in UTF-8.

Unfortunately, ATL is a sad old library from before IRI was a thing. When it sees non-ASCII escape sequences it decodes them to Unicode using your machine's locale-specific default (ANSI) code page, which is never UTF-8. For a Western European Windows install you get code page 1252, in which `%C3%84` means the two characters `Ã„`.

(It is possible this is a bug. In the version of atlutil.h I have to hand there is a preceding comment saying it doesn't matter what encoding is used because there are no non-ASCII characters, which is true for the code in `AtlEscapeUrl` above that it's carelessly copy-pasted from, but not at all true for `AtlUnescapeUrl`. This would seem to mean that the ATL escape and unescape functions don't use the same encodings and so don't round-trip... oops.)

To get around this problem you could do the Unicode bits yourself. Instead of calling the Unicode (LPWSTR) version of `AtlUnescapeUrl`, convert the input Unicode string into a byte string using the UTF-8 encoding (`MultiByteToWideChar` CP_UTF8), then call the byte (LPSTR) version of `AtlUnescapeUrl` on the byte string, and decode again (`WideCharToMultiByte` CP_UTF8).

Alternatively choose another, less-broken URL-handling library.